# Using Arraylist to show 'items' from one class in another

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Basically I have to program an eAuction java program. I have to 'View Auctions'. I have made an Array list in 'Item' class however I am struggling to connect this class with 'Auction' class in order for the user to view the items available to bid for.

This is my 'Item' class:

```
private static List<String> list;
private List myArr = null;
private List obj = null;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();

    myArr.add("Item: Aux cable");
    myArr.add("Description: 1.2m");
    myArr.add("Price: £4.50");

    System.out.println("Item list" + myArr);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();

    obj.add("Item: Laptop Case");
    obj.add("Description: Purple, 17inch");
    obj.add("Price: £7.00");

    System.out.println("Item list" + obj);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Item: Sony Headphones");
    list.add("Description: Black, Brown, Blue");
    list.add("Price: £15.00");

    System.out.println("Item list" + list);

}

public static List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}
}
```

This is my 'Auction' class.

```
public void display() {

    ArrayList<String> myArr = item.getList();
    System.out.print(myArr + "auction is still available" + ".");

}
```

This is the 'System1' class where the program will run from;

```
private static void viewAuctions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}
```

}

Comment: 1, what is "item" in the display method, 2, what is the problem?

Comment: With your current implementation your `getList()` method will always return *an empty list*, because local variable `list` declared in bottom of your `main()` method will hide `private static List<String> list` field declared outside `main()`.

Comment: I think, you should change your design. Your items has a name, a description and a price. You should define this properties as instance variable instead of arrays in Item class. And you should add Item class's object in ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you would want to pass your array into your display method.

```
     public void display(ArrayList<String> myArr) {

     System.out.print(myArr + "auction is still available" + ".");

}
```

Then from your main class simply create an Auction object and call the method passing in your ArrayList

```
    Auction auction = new Auction();
    auction.display(myArr);
```

Comment: When I enter Auction auction = new Auction();
    auction.display(myArr); into my main class it is not recognising myArr from the array.

Comment: Check your scope, are you calling it before the ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>(); line by any chace?  I copied your code into my eclipse and it worked when I made my changes.

Comment: thanks for the help so far you have got us further this is our result after your last comment "[]auction is still available."

Comment: Can you try debugging through your code line by line?  You need to see when your ArrayList is being populated, and call the display() method when it actually has some contents in it.  It seems like you are just passing an empty ArrayList right now.

Comment: We tried and still getting the same result. How did your code work so quickly?

Comment: Try this: ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
         Auction auction = new Auction();
         

         myArr.add("Item: Aux cable");
         myArr.add("Description: 1.2m");
         myArr.add("Price: £4.50");
         
         auction.display(myArr);

Comment: That worked fine but we are required to get the arrayList from 'item' class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your getList() method does. But if you want to print the content of your ArrayList, you should try:

```
for(String current : list) {
       System.out.println(current);
   }
or 
   list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: where abouts do we enter this code? In the system1 class?

Comment: You should insert the code at that point where you want to print the content of your list. If you have implemented a ui, you can't do this with System.out.println();. Than you have to add each element to your ListView (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the content of the arraylist and that is the only probelm, you need to run through the items in arraylist. printing `myArr` will just give you the whole object. So you could do something like,

```
for(String item:myArr){
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

a bit more code would be helpful. Also, your varaibles seems to be confusing, you could organise it more with the structure of application. There is a `list` local vairable and a `list` instance varaible. You might be confused which arraylist are you filling, right now it is just filling the local arrayList